# macOS .command file no permission

Tags: macos, server, minecraft

I'm trying to open a minecraft server for me and my friends and I am currently setting it up. But I don't have windows (I'm using a macOS) and ran into the problem that I had to use a .bat file and later learned that .command files were similar to .bat files and so I used that extension. However, when I ran it, it said,
"The file “run.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges."

No matter how I played with the settings, I just can't get it to start up. May I know how to solve this issue?

Anyway, here's the code: 
java -Xmx1G -jar server.jar
PAUSE

Where server.jar is the java executable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DGoldenberg8 said this in another topic:

> There is an easy fix. In terminal, CD to the directory of the file, then type in chmod u+x filename.command

Comment: Oh my god it worked! And I didn't read the post from him I didn't even see it